# PostgreSQL PHP - Use values of second table as column header and column description for values of first table in Excel/CSV export

Tags: php, sql, excel, postgresql

some time ago a big Excel file was imported into a PostgreSQL table.
The layout in Excel was like this (see list numbers as row numbers):

1. Some Column  |  Some other Column  |  Yet another one  |  ...
2. Descriptiontext foo |  Descriptiontext2  |  bar foo bar  |  ...
3. Value a  |  Value b  | Value c  | ...
4. Value aa  |  Value bb  | Value cc  | ...

So there was the header row with the column names, then a row with a description text for each column and after that hundreds of rows with all the values.

In PostgreSQL two tables where created.

Table1:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    t1_id integer NOT NULL
    col1 inet,
    some_other_col character varying,
    another_one integer,
    ...
);
```

Table2:

```
CREATE TABLE mapping (
    mapping_id integer NOT NULL
    colname character varying,
    mapping character varying,
    description character varying,
);

INSERT INTO mapping VALUES (1, 'col1', 'Some Column', 'Descriptiontext foo');
INSERT INTO mapping VALUES (2, 'some_other_col', 'Some other Column', 'Descriptiontext2');
INSERT INTO mapping VALUES (3, 'another_one', 'Yet another one', 'bar foo bar');
```

My question now is, how to merge these tables again to export an Excel sheet with the same format as the old one? And would I need PHP for that or is this possible using only SQL?

Comment: It's probably going to be a lot simpler with 2 queries in PHP. A first one to get the data from `mapping` and display the first two rows (one loop over the results for each), and another one to fetch the rest of the data and display them as individual rows.

Comment: @jcaron Seems reasonable to me - add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a **[FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html)** to merge both table with your desire format

Then use **[COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-copy.html)**  to create the excel file. No need to use php here

Comment: I guess this would be possible, but as far as I can see, Excel has problems with the UTF-8 data that is exported, so I have to go the PHP way and convert it first to UTF-16LE.

Comment: You can specify the encoding using the `ENCODING` function of `COPY`. Surprised you're having issues with UTF-8 though, what version of Excel is that? Note that you may have more options if you open the file from within Excel rather than just double-click on it and let Excel open it.

Comment: Its Excel 2010 and it has to work without any further doing as the people working with it, are no PC or Excel specialists. If eveything was in english, it would work, but the german letters are wrong in Excel if I use UTF-8. I'll have a look at the Encoding function though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to be a lot simpler with 2 queries in PHP:

1. A first one to get the data from `mapping` and display the first two rows (one loop over the results for each)
2. Another one to fetch the rest of the data and display them as individual rows

Comment: Hi @Picl, how did this go? Feel free to up vote and/or accept any answers or comments that helped you.

Comment: As many of us are ill atm, I had to work on other projects. I will answer and vote as soon as I had enough time to sort everything out. Sorry, for the delay.